# Send mail on session_start

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I want to invoke method (to sending a mail) in session_start.
This is my task function:

```
    Public Shared Async Function SendEmailMessage(ByVal MailFrom As String, ByVal MailTo As String, ByVal Subject As String, ByVal HtmlMessage As String) As Task

    Dim mail As MailMessage = New MailMessage


    mail.From = New MailAddress(MailFrom)

    mail.To.Add(MailTo)

    mail.Subject = Subject

    mail.Body = HtmlMessage

    Dim smtp As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient("smtpclient")
    smtp.Port = 587
    smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = True

    Await Task.Run(Function() smtp.SendMailAsync(mail))

    'Await result

End Function
```

In global.asax i have this code:

```
Public Overrides Sub Init()
    MyBase.Init()
    Dim wrapper = New EventHandlerTaskAsyncHelper(AsyncSessionStart)
    Me.AddOnAcquireRequestStateAsync(wrapper.BeginEventHandler, wrapper.EndEventHandler)
End Sub


Private Async Function AsyncSessionStart() As Task
    If Not Session.IsNewSession Then Return
    Await funzioni.SendEmailMessage("***@***.**", "*****@***", "Object text",
                                                    String.Format("E' stato effettuato un tentativo di accesso da {0} del {1} alla WebApp.",
                                                                  Session("name"), Session("office")))
End Function
```

this is the reference text that I have read and followed [asp-net-async-global-asax](https://www.ryadel.com/en/asp-net-async-global-asax/)

visual studio, however, gives me the following error in this part of the code:

```
Dim wrapper = New EventHandlerTaskAsyncHelper(AsyncSessionStart)
```

Value of type Task cannot be converted to TaskEventHandler.

where am i wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having tested, I believe that this:

```vb
Private Async Function AsyncSessionStart() As Task
```

should be this:

```vb
Private Async Sub AsyncSessionStart(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
```

The method you specify to the `EventHandlerTaskAsyncHelper` constructor should be an asynchronous event handler, which means using the standard event handler parameters (which the link you posted does but you ignored) and declaring it an `Async Sub`.

You also have to use the `AddressOf` operator to create a delegate in VB. You may also have to specify the delegate type explicitly:

```vb
Dim wrapper = New EventHandlerTaskAsyncHelper(AddressOf AsyncSessionStart)
```

or:

```vb
Dim wrapper = New EventHandlerTaskAsyncHelper(New TaskEventHandler(AddressOf AsyncSessionStart))
```

Comment: It's ok, but now i have this error: Session state is not available in this context!

Comment: Yeah, i changed Me.AddOnAcquireRequestStateAsync with Me.AddOnPostRequestHandlerExecuteAsync. now the method works!!!! Thank you very much!!!